# Holding a list in RAM in R

Tags: r

I am running a categorization algorithm.

- I have 47 models
- I test my input against each model.
- In total, the models take up 2.7GB of disk space.
- I store the models on disk using the `r.cache` package
- I retrieve the models from disk one by one and run predictions

So I thought it would make sense to load the models into RAM. This would save the io time and speed up the process.

I adjusted the function (see code below) to load the models into a list and hold the models in the global environment (assuming the global environment was in RAM).

However, there is NO change in function speed and there seems to be no change in RAM memory usage.

**Questions:**

Am I correct in now assuming that global environment variables are cached to disk?

Is it possible to hold a list of large memory footprint models in RAM (each model ranges from 50mb to 400mb)?

**The current code is as follows:**

*Notes:* loadCache is a method from the r.cache package. It loads a model from disk cache.
Obviously, this is test code. If it actually worked, I'd break it out into smaller functions

```
  if(is.null(modelsList))
  {
    modelsList=list()

    for(majorFinal in majorAsFactor)
    {
      print(paste("\n\n\n\npredicting.....",majorFinal))
      key=list(paste("KSVM",majorFinal,sep='_'))
      svm_model <- loadCache(key)
      modelsList[[count]] <- svm_model

      count <- count+1
      svm_pred <- predict(svm_model, onerowdfcache)

        if(as.character(svm_pred)!="OTHER")
        {

          results<-c(results,as.character(svm_pred))
          print(results)
        }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    count=as.numeric(1)
      for(svm_model in modelsList)
      {
        print(paste("\n\n\n\npredicting.....",count))
        count=count+1
        svm_pred <- predict(svm_model, onerowdfcache)

        if(as.character(svm_pred)!="OTHER")
        {


          results<-c(results,as.character(svm_pred))
          print(results)

        }

    }
  }
```

Comment: You can load as much data into R as your machine has RAM. Typically if you want to _do_ anything with that data, your object should only occupy maybe 1/3 of your machine's RAM. One reason your code may be slow is that you are growing both `results` and `modelsList` by appending items to them.

Comment: But not in the second condition. So one would expect the first condition to be slower, wouldn't one?

Comment: Well, you're growing `results` in both the `if` and the `else`. But the practical speed cost is impossible to say precisely bc I don't know how big your data are and how many iterations you're doing. If it's all very small, the speed cost would be minimal.

Comment: results is tiny (typically two strings of 10 characters). The models loaded from disk via r.cache in the first condition are huge, totalling 2.7GB. I thought the second concition had cut this out, but no difference in performance

Comment: Break up your script into components and measure how long each part takes with the `system.time()` function.  My guess is that loading the models from cache isn't taking any time.  If you frequently use a file from disk, most OSes will hold that in a memory buffer to load faster.  And RAM speed is ~10,000 MB/s.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. So I guess all the time is going to processing the model. I will save RAM and just read from disk each time. Thanks